# Возможно ли переполнение памяти

Tags: java

Есть следующий код программы. Он считает количество уникальных слов на странице. Могут ли тут быть ситуации переполнения памяти(кроме переполнения int)? Если да, то как их решить?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String newsHeadlines = doc.getAllElements().text()
                .replaceAll("[\\.\\,\\?\\!\\:\\;\\#\\%\\&\\^\\*\\(\\)\\_\\{\\}]", "")
                .replaceAll("\\[","")
                .replaceAll("\\]","")
                .replaceAll("[0-9]", "");


        List<String> newsList=Arrays.asList(newsHeadlines.split(" "));
        Set<String> uniq= new HashSet<String>(newsList);
        int count=0;
        for(String word : uniq){

            System.out.println(word+": "+ Collections.frequency(newsList, word));
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переполнение памяти возможно, как и в любой другой программе, если оперативной памяти будет меньше, чем использует программа. Но в вашем случае это очень маловероятно на современном железе. Сомневаюсь, что страничка в википедии будет настолько огромной, чтобы вызвать переполнение памяти.

Если вы будете выполнять этот фрагмент кода для серии страниц, а не для одной, то просто не храните странички, которые уже проанализировали. Тогда никакого переполнения памяти не будет.

И в случае с переполнением int тоже очень-очень маловероятно, что на странице будет настолько много уникальных слов.

Comment: Ни один словарь не содержит уникальных слов более int, даже если считать разными слова с различными окончаниями, то превысить int на одной странице HTML - это нереально.

Comment: В Java есть ограничение на максимальную длину массива, и, если страница очень большая, то на странице может оказаться слишком много слов. В таком случае `newsHeadlines.split` не сможет создать массив.